# ADC example with UART on Nordic evaluation board

Tags: uart, adc

I bought nordic evaluation board 2 days ago. I have been searching through the forums to enable and test the voltage level of a battery and monitor it via UART. After several hours of trail and error. I manage to combine two examples of nordic in to one but I am not being able to see the voltage level on my UART. Can you guys provide me with an example of ADC using UART as output. I will do the rest.

thanks

edit:

```
#include "simple_uart.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "nrf.h"
#include "nrf_gpio.h"
#include "boards.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h"


//#define ENABLE_LOOPBACK_TEST  /**< if defined, then this example will be a loopback test, which means that TX should be connected to RX to get data loopback. */

#define ERROR_PIN           (LED_0) /**< gpio pin number to show error if loopback is enabled. */
#define MAX_TEST_DATA_BYTES (15U)   /**< max number of test bytes to be used for tx and rx. */
#define LFCLK_FREQUENCY           (32768UL)                 /*!< LFCLK frequency in Hertz, constant */
#define RTC_FREQUENCY             (10UL)                     /*!< required RTC working clock RTC_FREQUENCY Hertz. Changable */
#define COUNTER_PRESCALER         ((LFCLK_FREQUENCY/RTC_FREQUENCY) - 1)  /* f = LFCLK/(prescaler + 1) */

/** Configures port 1 as output
 */
static void gpio_config(void)
{
  nrf_gpio_range_cfg_output(8, 15);
  nrf_gpio_port_write(NRF_GPIO_PORT_SELECT_PORT1, 0);
}

static void hfclk_config(void)
{
    /* Start 16 MHz crystal oscillator */
  NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_HFCLKSTARTED = 0;
  NRF_CLOCK->TASKS_HFCLKSTART = 1;

  /* Wait for the external oscillator to start up */
  while (NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_HFCLKSTARTED == 0) {}
}

static void lfclk_config(void)
{
  NRF_CLOCK->LFCLKSRC = (CLOCK_LFCLKSRC_SRC_Xtal << CLOCK_LFCLKSRC_SRC_Pos);
  NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_LFCLKSTARTED = 0;
  NRF_CLOCK->TASKS_LFCLKSTART = 1;

    // Wait for the low frequency clock to start
  while (NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_LFCLKSTARTED == 0) {}
  NRF_CLOCK->EVENTS_LFCLKSTARTED = 0;
}

/** Configure and start RTC
 */
static void rtc_config(void)
{
  NRF_RTC0->PRESCALER = COUNTER_PRESCALER;                   // Set prescaler to a TICK of RTC_FREQUENCY
  NRF_RTC0->EVTENSET = RTC_EVTENSET_TICK_Msk;                // Enable TICK event   
    NRF_RTC0->TASKS_START = 1;                                 // Start RTC0
}

static void ppi_init(void)
{
  // Configure PPI channel 0 to start ADC task
  NRF_PPI->CH[0].EEP = (uint32_t)&NRF_RTC0->EVENTS_TICK;
  NRF_PPI->CH[0].TEP = (uint32_t)&NRF_ADC->TASKS_START;

  // Enable PPI channel 0
  NRF_PPI->CHEN = (PPI_CHEN_CH0_Enabled << PPI_CHEN_CH0_Pos);
}

/** Configures and enables the ADC
 */
void ADC_init(void)
{   
    /* Enable interrupt on ADC sample ready event*/     
    NRF_ADC->INTENSET = ADC_INTENSET_END_Msk;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);   

    // config ADC
    NRF_ADC->CONFIG = (ADC_CONFIG_EXTREFSEL_None << ADC_CONFIG_EXTREFSEL_Pos)                               /* Bits 17..16 : ADC external reference pin selection. */
                                        | (ADC_CONFIG_PSEL_AnalogInput6 << ADC_CONFIG_PSEL_Pos)                                 /*!< Use analog input 6 as analog input (P0.05). */
                                        | (ADC_CONFIG_REFSEL_VBG << ADC_CONFIG_REFSEL_Pos)                                          /*!< Use internal 1.2V bandgap voltage as reference for conversion. */
                                        | (ADC_CONFIG_INPSEL_AnalogInputNoPrescaling << ADC_CONFIG_INPSEL_Pos)  /*!< Analog input specified by PSEL with no prescaling used as input for the conversion. */
                                        | (ADC_CONFIG_RES_8bit << ADC_CONFIG_RES_Pos);                                                  /*!< 8bit ADC resolution. */    


    /* Enable ADC*/
    NRF_ADC->ENABLE = ADC_ENABLE_ENABLE_Enabled;    
}

/* Interrupt handler for ADC data ready event. It will be executed when ADC sampling is complete */
void ADC_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* Clear dataready event */
  NRF_ADC->EVENTS_END = 0;  

  /* Write ADC result to port 1 */
    //simple_uart_putstring((const uint8_t *) NRF_ADC->RESULT);       

    //nrf_gpio_port_write(NRF_GPIO_PORT_SELECT_PORT1, NRF_ADC->RESULT); 
}

#ifndef ENABLE_LOOPBACK_TEST

/** @brief Function for sending 'Exit!' string to UART. 
 * 
 *  @note Execution is blocked until UART peripheral detects all characters have been sent.
 */
static __INLINE void uart_quit()
{
    simple_uart_putstring((const uint8_t *)" \n\rExit!\n\r");
}


/** @brief Function for sending 'Start:' string to UART. 
 *  @details Execution is blocked until UART peripheral detects all characters have been sent.
 */
static __INLINE void uart_start()
{
    simple_uart_putstring((const uint8_t *)" \n\rStart: ");
}
#else

/** @brief Function for setting the @ref ERROR_PIN high, and then enter an infinite loop.
 *  This function is called if any of the nRF6350 functions fail.
 */
static void show_error(void)
{
    nrf_gpio_pin_write(ERROR_PIN, 1);
    while(true)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}


/** @brief Function for testing UART loop back. 
 *  @details Transmitts one character at a time to check if the data received from the loopback is same as the transmitted data.
 *  @note  @ref TX_PIN_NUMBER must be connected to @ref RX_PIN_NUMBER)
 */
static void uart_loopback_test()
{
    uint8_t *tx_data = (uint8_t *)("\n\rLOOPBACK_TEST");
    uint8_t  rx_data;

    // Start sending one byte and see if you get the same
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < MAX_TEST_DATA_BYTES; i++)
    {
        bool status;
        simple_uart_put(tx_data[i]);
        status = simple_uart_get_with_timeout(2, &rx_data);

        if ((rx_data != tx_data[i]) || (!status))
        {
            show_error();
        }
    }
    return; 
}
#endif


/**
 * @brief Function for main application entry.
 */
int main(void)
{
        char buffer[20U];
    simple_uart_config(RTS_PIN_NUMBER, TX_PIN_NUMBER, CTS_PIN_NUMBER, RX_PIN_NUMBER, HWFC);

    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(ERROR_PIN); // ERROR_PIN configured as output.
        nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_0);
        nrf_gpio_pin_clear(LED_0);
        gpio_config();
        lfclk_config();
        rtc_config();
        ppi_init();
        ADC_init();

#ifndef ENABLE_LOOPBACK_TEST
    uart_start();
    while (true)
    {
            uint8_t cr = simple_uart_get();
      simple_uart_put(cr);
            uint8_t adc_result = (float) NRF_ADC->RESULT;


            switch(cr)
                {
                    case ('q'):
                        uart_quit();
                        while(true)
                        {
                            //Do nothing
                        }
                        break;
                    case ('1'):
                    {
                        nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_0);
                        sprintf (buffer, "value: %05u", adc_result);
                        simple_uart_putstring((uint8_t*)buffer);

                    }
                    break;
                    case ('2'):
                    {
                        nrf_gpio_pin_clear(LED_0);
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                    {

                    }
                }
    }
#else
  // This part of the example is just for testing the loopback .
  while(true)
  {
    uart_loopback_test();
  }
#endif
}
/** @} */
```

Comment: You should probably post the code you have written so far so that people here can help you to fix it.

Comment: You haven't properly defined what you want to do.  The ADC will provide data as a 8-bit (or maybe 10-bit or whatever its resolution) binary integer value.  It's not a voltage; it has no dimensional unit.  Is the UART to output this unconverted binary data, or is it to be scaled, converted to a voltage value and/or converted to ASCII text?

Comment: I just made an edit with my code